# Is there a way to bring up the method signatures in Phpstorm's autocomplete?

Tags: phpstorm

As per most IDE's, PhpStorm will bring up a list of matching options when you type part of a function (assuming the IDE is configured properly etc).
PhpStorm, will also show the function signature, which is ideal, for giving hints when you have a function that accepts lots of parameters, e.g. database connection functions like `mysqli_connect`.
However, the moment you "select" the function for autocompletion, either by `ctrl + spacebar` or selecting from dropdown menu, the method signature and parameter hinting disapears.

Ive tried:

- `ctrl + space` this brings up the autocomplete menu again, but you have to fiddle with the window to view the params, then it disappears again when you start typing, and if you need to reference again, you need to go through the window resizing process again.
- `ctrl + q` quick documentation - this doesnt do anything

Is there a way to bring the method signature back up while typing out the parameters for the function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in the default keybinding with:

```
ctrl+p
```

Comment: Will do for sure ! have already upvoted, need to wait 10mins before StackOverflow will allow me to accpet answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In the previous versions of PHP Storm this was possible by using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd> .

But they have changed it, now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd>  opens the **Print** dialog.

My current version is 2016.3.2, and the new shortcut for it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can see the shortcut in View > Parameter Info

[image]

**EDIT:** This is for Windows only, on Linux the shortcut is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.